# how do I publish a website made with xampp?

Tags: php

I made a Web site local with xampp in codeigniter and I want to make it public. I installed joomla 3.0.3 control panel provided with the domain, but I don't know how to adapt it so that it appears online. Is it possible to do this? If so, I'd like some guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very basic, you need to read more about how to uploading my files into my host? how to use cpanel? etc...

Comment: It sounds like you're using some kind of hosting provider. This is probably a questions that should be directed at them

Comment: I uploaded files in public_html.

Comment: If you developed in CodeIgniter, why did you installed Joomla? And what about all those tags? Is your site in Joomla, Codeigniter or both? Did you use Smarty in Codeigniter, Joomla, and anyway what does it have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter and Joomla are two different things.

Codeigniter is an application development framework for php.

Joomla is a very powerful and popular Content Management System.

If your website is ready, leave joomla and load your codeigniter based website files from your  test environment to the webserver using your preferred migration technique.

You can explore joomla and see if it suites you. You might then want to use Joomla! for creating your website/s. It used PHP and is very user friendly.

Now, for moving your developemnt for localserver to webserver

- you will need to move the files to the webserver from your local maching using the FTP given by your hosting provider.
- Once the php/html/css/js/image etc files are loaded on the webserver, you will have to use the hosting providers phpmyadmin link to create a replica of your local machine's database (most probably your hosting provider would have also provided MySQL as database).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to point your domain directly to your files and use xampp as a live server, I highly recommend against that. Xampp is meant to be used as a development server, NOT a production server. It does not have the security features that a live server needs to prevent security breaches.

If you are trying to deploy your files currently on xampp to a live server, I highly recommend reading about Git, FTP, and the basics of whatever web host/server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is for local (localhost) development.

It's okay that you've developed your site on XAMPP, but you'll need to get some secure hosting solutions and purchase a unique domain name, then FTP the site code you've developed and tested on XAMPP to that webserver using some [FTP Solution](http://filezilla-project.org/).